# Issues with buttons in javas calculator

Tags: java, applet

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class H4 extends Applet
  implements ActionListener{
    float f1, s1 ,sum1, f2, s2, sum2, f3, s3, sum3, f4, s4, sum4;                 
    TextField a1, b1, eq1, a2, b2, eq2, a3, b3, eq3, a4, b4, eq4;
    Button equal1, equal2, equal3, equal4;

  public void init() {
      resize(800,600);
  
      equal1 = new Button("=");
      equal2 = new Button("=");
      equal3 = new Button("=");
      equal4 = new Button("=");
      
      a1 = new TextField(12);
      b1 = new TextField(12);
      eq1 = new TextField(12);
      
      a2 = new TextField(12);
      b2 = new TextField(12);
      eq2 = new TextField(12);
      
      a3 = new TextField(12);
      b3 = new TextField(12);
      eq3 = new TextField(12);
      
      a4 = new TextField(12);
      b4 = new TextField(12);
      eq4 = new TextField(12);
      
      Label plus = new Label("+");
      Label minus = new Label("-");
      Label multiply = new Label("*");
      Label divide = new Label("/");
      
      
      setLayout(null);
      
      a1.setBounds(60, 20, 40, 20);
      b1.setBounds(120, 20, 40, 20);
      eq1.setBounds(190, 20, 40, 20);
      equal1.setBounds(165, 19, 20, 20);
      plus.setBounds(103, 20, 40, 20);
      
      a2.setBounds(60, 50, 40, 20);
      b2.setBounds(120, 50, 40, 20);
      eq2.setBounds(190, 50, 40, 20);
      equal2.setBounds(165, 49, 20, 20);
      minus.setBounds(103, 50, 40, 20);
      
      a3.setBounds(60, 80, 40, 20);
      b3.setBounds(120, 80, 40, 20);
      eq3.setBounds(190, 80, 40, 20);
      equal3.setBounds(165, 79, 20, 20);
      multiply.setBounds(103, 80, 40, 20);
      
      a4.setBounds(60, 110, 40, 20);
      b4.setBounds(120, 110, 40, 20);
      eq4.setBounds(190, 110, 40, 20);
      equal4.setBounds(165, 109, 20, 20);
      divide.setBounds(103, 110, 40, 20);
      
      add(a1);
      add(b1);
      add(equal1);
      add(eq1);
      add(plus);
      
      add(a2);
      add(b2);
      add(equal2);
      add(eq2);
      add(minus);
      
      add(a3);
      add(b3);
      add(equal3);
      add(eq3);
      add(multiply);
      
      add(a4);
      add(b4);
      add(equal4);
      add(eq4);
      add(divide);
      
      equal1.addActionListener(this);
      equal2.addActionListener(this);
      equal3.addActionListener(this);
      equal4.addActionListener(this);
    
  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      if(a1.getText()!= null || b1.getText()!= null){
      f1 = Float.valueOf(a1.getText()).floatValue();
      s1 = Float.valueOf(b1.getText()).floatValue();
      sum1 = f1 + s1;
      eq1.setText(Float.toString(sum1));
      }
      else if (a2.getText()!= null || b2.getText()!= null){
      f2 = Float.valueOf(a2.getText()).floatValue();
      s2 = Float.valueOf(b2.getText()).floatValue();
      sum2 = f2 - s2;
      eq2.setText(Float.toString(sum2));
      }
      else if (a3.getText()!= null || b3.getText()!= null) {
      f3 = Float.valueOf(a3.getText()).floatValue();
      s3 = Float.valueOf(b3.getText()).floatValue();
      sum3 = f3 * s3;
      eq3.setText(Float.toString(sum3));
      }
      else{
      f4 = Float.valueOf(a4.getText()).floatValue();
      s4 = Float.valueOf(b4.getText()).floatValue();
      sum4 = f4 / s4;
      eq4.setText(Float.toString(sum4));
      }
}}
```

The **problem** is that when i click on the button are activated all 4 buttons, i have tried to fix that, but i could do that. I tried to get text from testfiels and check if it doesnt equal null but programm works only with first button others doesnt work at all. Can someone help me with that problem? I m using old librarry applets because i m studing in the university, and my teacher is old and she doesnt even now new versions of java she is just gaving us exercises with code examples thats what i try to do.

Comment: When you click on what button?

Comment: Like when i clicked on any button activated all buttons and i tried to add if else to fix it but now works only first button but when i click on others its doesnt work.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two solutions:

(1) You can check which action (button) triggered the event with `ActionEvent#getSource()`. This method is inherited from `EventObject` and the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource()) read:

> public Object getSource()
>
> The object on which the Event initially occurred.
>
> Returns:
> The object on which the Event initially occurred.

Example:

```java
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  Object source = e.getSource();

  if(source.equals(equals1) {
    // Button "equals1" was clicked.
  } else if(source.equals(equals2)) {
    // Button "equals2" was clicked.
  } else if...
}
```

(2) Use separate methods for each button.

```java
equals1.addActionListener(this::equals1Clicked);
equals2.addActionListener(this::equals2Clicked);
...

public void equals1Clicked(ActionEvent e) {
  // Button "equals1" was clicked.
}

public void equals2Clicked(ActionEvent e) {
  // Button "equals2" was clicked.
}
```